# How to debug Linux TUI applications for Raspberry Pi using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, debugging, command-line

I've been writing a C++ TUI application to run in the terminal of my raspberry pi using the ncurses library. I've been doing this using the linux remote C++ development add-on in Visual Studio, but I've run into some hurdles into how I should go about debugging it.

Built into visual studio there is a linux console window which displays the output of the ssh connection visual studio makes with the raspberry pi, so if you're writing a console interface using nothing but std::cout and std::cin it does the job for interacting and debugging the app. Ncurses however does not use the standard input and output streams, and therefore the ncurses interface written in code does not appear in the linux console window.

Therefore, essentially what I want to be able to do is interact with the output of my application on my raspberry pi screen when I build and run my linux solution in visual studio instead of using the linux console window. I want a terminal window with my ncurses application running in debug mode to spawn in on the primary display of my raspberry pi, whilst still having the full debug controls for it in visual studio (like breakpoints and such). I do not know how to do this though.

[image: Pre-launch Command property]

I have seen in other tutorials for debugging GUI applcations (using, for example, GTK) written for linux using visual studio that the "Pre-launch Command" property found in the debug properties page of the C++ Linux project might be the key to do this. In the GTK GUI tutorial, they put the command *export DISPLAY=:0.0* in this property in order for the GUI application in debug mode to spawn in on the primary display of the raspberry pi. This does not work for TUI applications however. I am hoping therefore for the solution to my problem being as simple as finding the right argument to put in this property.

The link to the GUI tutorial I'm referring to here is http://comfilewiki.co.kr/en/doku.php?id=comfilepi:create_a_linux_project:index#specify_the_include_paths_in_the_project_s_properties

Thank you to whoever helps me out.

Comment: The DISPLAY variable is for X11 applications. You need a terminal emulator instead.

Answer (score 2):

A [RaspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) can run some Linux distribution derived from Debian, e.g. [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/).

A RaspberryPi has wifi and ethernet. You should be able to configure them to serve [ssh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html) thru [sshd(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sshd.8.html) either thru wifi or thru ethernet.

Once an `sshd` server is running on your RaspBerryPi, you just use `ssh` on your Linux cross-development machine to access it on the command line.

The [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) debugger has [remote debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html) facilities, but you could just run it on the RaspBerryPi accessed thru `ssh`

> I've been writing a C++ TUI application to run in the terminal of my raspberry pi using the ncurses library.

I have a simpler recommendation :

### debug your C++ TUI application on your laptop or desktop running some Linux distribution.

Only once it is debugged cross-compile it for your RaspBerryPi.

Most C++ applications can be written with enough care to be easily [ported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) from Debian running on your x86-64 laptop to Raspbian running on your RaspberryPi. Be careful to stick to the C++11 (read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) or C++17 standard. [Enable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) most warnings when compiling with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), even if it is a cross-compiler. So use at least `g++ -g -Wall -Wextra` and improve your C++ source code to minimize compiler warnings.

### Recommandation: install some Linux distribution on your development laptop or desktop.

For that you just need less than a hundred gigabytes of consecutive free disk space. Both [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) and [Debian](https://debian.org/) are very easy to install, and freely downloadable.

Once Linux is running on your laptop or desktop, and Raspbian is running on your RaspberryPi, you just need to connect them e.g. using an Ethernet cable.

I recommend installing the `build-essential` and `crossbuild-essential-arm64` packages on Debian (or Ubuntu) on your Linux laptop. Also consider installing the [git](https://git-scm.com/) version control, the [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor (and/or [geany](https://www.geany.org/) and/or [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)), the [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger, the [`g++` compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/), the [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) documentation generator, perhaps the [Qt](https://qt.io/) graphical toolkit, the [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) build automation tool, the  [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) and/or [Python](https://python.org/) and/or [Lua](https://lua.org/) and/or [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) scripting language

Don't forget to spend a few days in reading documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was already aiming to run Linux on my laptop in the near future, so thank you for the advice regarding that alternative solution. Did you happen to have any advice regarding visual studio commands though?

Comment: Visual Studio can be replaced by `emacs` or `geany`. And *visual studio code* is packaged for Linux